# I need to scrape logs from cloud watch logs and load it to s3 and from s3 to data warehouse

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have several lambda functions. I need to scrape my logs generated from all of my lambda functions and load to our internal data warehouse. I thought of these solutions.

1. Have a lambda function subscribed to my lambda function's cloudwatch log groups and polish and log messages and push it to s3.

   - Pros: Works and simple to implement.
   - Cons: There is no way for me to
     "replay". Say My exporter failed for some reason. I wouldn't be able
     to replay this action.
2. Have a lambda function that runs every 10 min or so and creates export task and scrapes logs from cloudwatch and loads them to s3.

   ```
   import boto3
   client = boto3.client('logs')
   response = client.create_export_task(
   taskName='export_task',
   logGroupName='/aws/lambda/<lambda_function_1>',
   fromTime=from_time,
   to=to_time,
   destination='<application_logs>',
   destinationPrefix='<lambda_function_1>'
   )


   response = client.create_export_task(
   taskName='export_task',
   logGroupName='/aws/lambda/<lambda_function_2>',
   fromTime=from_time,
   to=to_time,
   destination='<application_logs>',
   destinationPrefix='<lambda_function_2>'
   ```

   )

   Second create_export_task fails here

   ```
    An error occurred (LimitExceededException) when calling the 
    CreateExportTask operation: Resource limit exceeded."
   ```

I cant create multiple export task. Is there a way to address this?

Answer (score 4):

From AWS docs: `One active (running or pending) export task at a time, per account. This limit cannot be changed.`

U can use the below function to check if the status has been changed to `'COMPLETED'`

```
response = client.create_export_task(
            taskName='export_cw_to_s3',
            logGroupName='/ecs/',
            logStreamNamePrefix=org_id,
            fromTime=int((yesterday-unix_start).total_seconds() * 1000),
            to=int((today-unix_start).total_seconds() * 1000),
            destination='test-bucket',
            destinationPrefix=f'random-string/{today.year}/{today.month}/{today.day}/{org_id}')
        taskId = (response['taskId'])
        status = 'RUNNING'
        while status in ['RUNNING','PENDING']:
            response_desc = client.describe_export_tasks(
                taskId=taskId
            )

            status = response_desc['exportTasks'][0]['status']['code']
```

Answer (score 2):

Came across the same error message and the reason is you can only have one running/pending export task per account at a given time hence this task is failing. From AWS docs: `One active (running or pending) export task at a time, per account. This limit cannot be changed.`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes one createExport task stays in pending state for long preventing other lambda functions with the same task to run. You could see this task and cancel it allowing the other functions to run.